# Marionette collection view multiple dom append

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following template to be used in a marionette application.
I have a collection of tabs. When i add a new tab item, i have two different areas to insert dom. Marionette.CollectionView appends dom only at one place. What should i use for a solution. I could override appendHtml method but, then i need some work when removing the tabs.
What is the simple approach to allow insertion/deletion in multiple areas.

```
 <script type='text/template' id="homeTabTemplate">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tablist">
        <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <!-- #1 append li tab here -->
     </ul>

     <div class="tab-content" id="tabcontent">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
         </div>
         <!-- #2 append tab-pane here -->
     </div>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to have 2 views that refer to the *same* isntance collection.

When you add/remove from that collection, both view will update automagically.

To manage both of these sub-views as one single "logical" view, use a Marionette layout.

Comment: I define a view just for a single li element?

Comment: You can do that (e.g. https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/header/list/list_view.js#L4), or you can use one single item view for the entire collection (e.g. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#rendering-a-collection-in-an-itemview). In both cases, the views will update when the collection changes (use you use a single item view, don't forget to lsiten to the collection events!).